# Taanis Bechoros for a first born from a C-section

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover, bechor-firstborn, taanis-bechoros

Does someone who was a first born, but was born from a C-section have to fast on Ta'anis Bechoros?

The only source I know which addresses this is the Kaf HaChaim on Shulchan Aruch ([470:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9084&st=&pgnum=239)), who says that it's a safek, and since it's only a chashash there is no need to be strict.

**I was wondering if anyone knew of any other sources and/or if there is consensus.**

Comment: Interesting question.  I would assume yes because the fact relates to the killing of the first-born in Egypt, not to the dedication of first-born to the temple.  But the latter is connected to the former, so...hmm!

Comment: Chok Yaakov 470:2

Comment: Editing into your question why you think a cesarean baby might be an exception would improve the question vastly.

Comment: When I asked my Rav this question (ages ago now), the reason I thought of the question is because I had previously learned that someone born by C-Section was patur from pidyon haben, and had recently read that someone born by C-Section also does not recieve the double portion of the inheritance due to the bechor. Since these mitzvot/rights didn't apply to me, I reasoned that maybe the halacha didn't see me as a bechor at all, for any reason. (My Rav answered by pointing me to the Kaf HaHayyim 470:3, whose ruling is described below.)

Answer (score 6):

According to the always-reliable [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_of_the_Firstborn#Qualifications_for_fasting), this is a machlokes. R' Elyashiv recommends participating in a seudas mitzva, and thus, breaking the fast early, in order to avoid this problem.

> There is some discussion among the poskim (halakhic authorities) regarding whether a firstborn born through caesarean section is required to observe this fast, given that he is not obligated in the Redemption of the Firstborn. The [Chok Ya'akov (470:2)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49401&st=&pgnum=94) suggests that such a firstborn may be required to fast, while the [Kaf HaChayyim (470:3)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9084&st=&pgnum=239) rules that he need not fast. To circumvent this question, as well as [the] dispute regarding a firstborn non-Jew who converts to Judaism, Rabbi Yosef Shalom Elyashiv ([Ha]Seder Ha'aruch, Vol. 3, p. 44) suggests that such firstborns participate in a seudat mitzvah

H/T to Michoel for pointing out a flaw in the Wiki article, and to Fred (probably) for correcting it.

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to say there is a machlokes between the Chok Yaakov and Kaf HaChaim. The Chok Yaakov questions whether such a firstborn should fast, and the Kaf ChaChaim quotes him and rules that he does not need to. (Link to [Kaf HaChaim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9084&st=&pgnum=239))

Comment: @Michoel Ah, I found the link at the same time you posted it. Interesting, you seem to be right about the Chok Yaakov; if he's saying anything, it's that he shouldn't fast. Hm, I'd like to see the Seder Ha'aruch inside, to see his sources, but I can't find one online.

Comment: We have the set in the shul I daven in, so I can take a look a bit later.

Comment: I haven't worked my way through this yet, but it looks promising: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=28075&st=&pgnum=28

Comment: @Michoel See [this revision](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fast_of_the_Firstborn&diff=546839548&oldid=543616011).

Comment: Here's the relevant quote from Haseder Haaruch: בכור יוצא דופן אפשר שיש לו שם בכור לעניין תענית בערב פסח. חק יעקב תע, ב. מרן הגרי"ש אלישיב הורה בזה שישתתף בסעודת מצוה,  כמבואר להלן סי' ה

Comment: @Fred Nice, is that your work?

Comment: @Michoel Thanks for looking that up! Also, thanks for the correction on the Wiki article.

Comment: @Michoel Yeah, I added in the error 5 years ago. Don't know what I was thinking at the time. (Not so "always reliable" I guess. Sorry, Hod).

Comment: @Fred LOL! [15c]